# Deprecated function from wincrypt

Tags: c, cryptoapi, certificate-store, wincrypt

What does it mean that a function, in particular `CryptExportPKCS8` is deprecated? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379932(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm aware that one can't use it with newer version of `wincrypt` just because it is not present in header file, but can a program based on old `wincrypt.h` and `crypt32.lib` still retrieve private key from certificate store in Windows 10? Or is it impossible to access such data without using more up-to-date API?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means "going away, change your code".  In this case, it appears that MS wants you to use `PFXExportCertStoreEx()` instead.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all - I can read the first line of the link I provided myself. The question is whether the deprecated function still works given deprecated API, correct implementation and modern system.

Comment: Who knows.  The only way to know is to try it.  But even if it does work, you are playing with fire, any future update could make it stop working.